# Serial downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have develop the habit of not taking the downvote too personal, but perhaps all of [my recent questions](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/5400/ooker?tab=questions&sort=newest) has an automatic downvote. I don't try to attack anyone or defend anything, but simply wonder why they think the my questions are bad. Before asking anything I have tried researching with my best. If they have enough knowledge why my questions are bad, then perhaps they know more about me, and I respect them. But without explanations I don't know where to improve.

Comment: **Note: I only downvoted 3 of your questions because I thought them were unclear.**

Comment: I see. With this questions, do you feel that you don't know where to ask me questions to make it clear?